# Is anarchism opposed to the concept of god?

Tags: government, political-system, religion

Why the negation of God by plenty of anarchists? I understand the negation of organized religion, because it confines and subdues the masses if each individual does not think or questions the human religion authority in itself. But outside religious organizations there can be belief in God without oppressing the people.

Comment: Many people are atheists. Anarchists are people. Do you think anarchists tend to be more atheist than the general population? Is it based on data?

Comment: «According to the website The Atheist Scholar: Most anarchists, past and present, are atheists. Their slogan is: “No god, No master.”»

Comment: Are you asking about the negation of a specific god, or the negation of the concept of gods in general? The idea of gods isn't very well defined outside of an organised religion.

Comment: @Erik Although there are millions of gods in Indian religions, in this case you can we can refer to the Abrahamic God, for sake of simplicity.

Comment: @guerrier When you say "their slogan", is there a particular group you are referring to?

Comment: @origimbo That whole phrase is an extract from the Wikipedia. I just posted as a reference where I assume most anarchists are atheists.

Comment: That is showing up for me in a google search as a quotation from Conservapedia rather than Wikipedia. Those two websites have somewhat different opinions on what constitutes a biased statement.

Comment: @origimbo Sorry, my mistake. I drew back the name from memory and I thought it was Wikipedia. Sorry again.

Comment: Maybe it depends also on the type of anarchist (anarcho-communist vs anarcho-capitalist). Personally (not scientific at all), I see more anarcho-communist that hate the idea of a god and more anarcho-capitalist that love or respect the idea of a god.

Comment: I think OP might be mistaking correlation for causation. Starting from a theology of a personal sovereign deity it can be hard to arrive at anarchism as a valid political philosophy, so maybe the religious are less likely to become anarchists.

Answer (score 10):

> Why the negation of god by plenty of anarchists?

It is clearly not true for all of them. Just like there are socialist theologians, who justified the implementation of socialism based on "Christian principles", there are [Christian anarchists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_anarchism), who justify the implementation of anarchism based on "Christian principles" (I use the quotes because Christian principles have been used to justify about everything).

> There can be a belief in god without oppressing the people

Anarchists are fundamentally egalitarian (some of them were sexist, anarchism worked well in the 19th century, but they at least require an equal status between men). So any kingdom founded by god would be a pretty hard thing to swallow (Solomon, Muhammad, ...). Any religiously imposed law can be quite contradictory to anarchism. One would have to discard a part of the texts and have a low level of religiosity (like the Christian anarchists mentioned earlier). Similarly, the privileged status of "prophet" can be quite contradictory, the "final judgement", and so on.

Historically, most of the anarchists have been indeed either *materialists* (there is only physical matter) or *deists* (there is a kind of supreme being/prime mover/creator that does not intervene in human affairs whatsoever, see for instance Einstein, Voltaire or Spinoza's view). Both positions are very close to atheism (deists have no prophets or church of any kind, unlike theists, the believers). The materialist position was very common among 19th century socialist thinkers, and the deism is arguably inherited from the enlightenment or the French revolution. One of the founders of anarchism, Pierre-Joseph Proudhon, stated pretty clearly that religion was useless at [the beginning of "Justice in the Revolution and in the church"](http://workingtranslations.blogspot.fr/p/pierre-joseph-proudhon-justice-in.html).

So if some day you find a poll about the religious position of anarchists, I would not be surprised to see a lower level of religiosity than in the general population. By low level of religiosity, I mean not only a high percentage of atheists, but also agnostics, deists, non-affiliated, apatheists, ...

> Their slogan is "no gods, no masters"

There is no "official" slogan; it would somehow go against the anarchist principle, but it is indeed used a lot (and comes from a non-anarchist, [Louis Auguste Blanqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Auguste_Blanqui)). A slogan is something very catchy, but it does not necessarily explain a lot. It does not include the "god no master" anarchists and can be used by non-anarchists for totally different reasons (I heard exactly the same slogan from a Senegalese animist once).